# Menu bar in FragmentActivity (Android)

Tags: android

I am trying to show an action bar menu in an activity that extends `FragmentActivity`, but it does not show. I have read that the method `setHasOptionsMenu` can make it work, but it is only recognized by the `Fragment` class.

Thus, how can I display the menu bar inside a class that inherits from `FragmentActivity` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend AppCompatActivity, this already extends FragmentActivity itself.